# Can not create mock of the final class, when Retryable is used

Tags: spring, unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, spring-retry

I have spring boot application with kotlin, and the thing is: I can't mock 3rd party final class only when @Retryable is used. Here is my project:

```
@Component
class RestClient {
    fun getAllData() : List<String> = listOf("1") 
}
```

```
@Service
class MyService(val restClient: RestClient) {

    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 3)
    fun makeRestCall() : List<String> {
        return restClient.getAllData()       
    }   
}
```

So I would like to test two cases:

- when `RestClient` throws HttpClientErrorException.NotFound exception,
  `makeRestCall()` should return `null` (that is not supported by
  current implementation by that does not matter)
- when `makeRestCall()` is invoked - I would like to check with mockito that it is really invoked (no sense, but why can't I do it? )

Here is my test:

```
@EnableRetry
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
class TTest {

    @MockBean
    lateinit var restClient: RestClient

    @SpyBean
    lateinit var myService: MyService

    @Test
    fun `should throw exception`() {
        val notFoundException = mock<HttpClientErrorException.NotFound>()
        whenever(restClient.getAllData()).thenThrow(notFoundException)
    }

    @Test
    fun `method should be invoked`() {
        myService.makeRestCall()
        verify(myService).makeRestCall()
    }
}
```

In order to mock final class `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.NotFound`, I've added mockito-inline as dependency

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
```

So, here is the problem:

when I run my tests **with mockito-inline** as dependency:

- test `should throw exception` - passes
- test `method should be invoked` - fails with exception :`Argument passed to verify() is of type MyService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$222fb0be and is not a mock!`

when I run my tests **without mockito-inline** as dependency:

- test `should throw exception` - fails with exception: `Mockito cannot mock/spy because : final class`
- test `method should be invoked - passes

when I run my tests **without @EnableRetry** - both tests passes, but I'm not able to test retry functionality

How can I deal with that?

Comment: is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478665/springs-retryable-not-working-when-running-junit-test

Comment: @Jocke no, my current post is about bug with mockito, not with Retryable

Comment: Then report that bug to the Mockito team. However I guess that select is not broken...